Make Wildfly CA certificate known
how can I make my own CA root certificates known in Wildfly?
So far I have entered the CA certificates in the cacerts keystore. However, I find this way unattractive, as this setting applies globally. However, I am looking for a way to make the certificates known specifically for a WildFly instance or for a standalone instance.
Is there a configuration option in the standalone.xml
